# Carousel view or Custom Render Tabs?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have question - what is rightn and correct way to implement this design in Xamarin (Xamarin forms)
[Design principle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLD62.png)

I see here 2 ways for implementations:

First way - is `TabbedPage`. And right `Custom Render` (For IOS - move tabs to top, and for android - Icons)

Second way - is `CarouselView` - but not sure is good.

Additional requirements is - Animation switch between content of "tabs"
Switch by finger slide is **NICE TO HAVE** option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no right and wrong way. There is only what meets your requirements and what is easiest to implement and maintain.

Your linked picture clearly shows a TabbedPage. However your additional requirements would make this an issue. iOS shows the tabs at the bottom. I'm not sure if it is easy to move them to the top. It would require a custom renderer if it is even possible. I think iOS allows you to swipe between tabbed pages but I'm not sure that Android does.

It would probably be easier to implement a CarouselView with buttons above. That way you will be able to place your buttons where you like, allow you to swipe between them and have animation. This meets all your requirements.